# Grouping random sequence into array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a text file, containing 2 different types of data: “NAMES” and “ACTIONS”, each type is repeated in random sequence throughout the text file:

```
NAME: joe 
ACTION: running 
NAME: paul 
ACTION: walking 
ACTION: swimming 
NAME: mary 
NAME: joe 
ACTION: sleeping 
NAME: paul 
NAME: mary 
NAME: ken 
ACTION: jumping 
ACTION: running 
ACTION: eating
```

I’m trying to create an array of objects that by concatenating each type of data, so that every object will hold only one pair of NAMES and ACTIONS, like this:

```
{   
    “name”: joe,
    “action” : running
}

{   
    “name: paul,
    “action” : walking swimming 
}

{   
    “name: mary joe, 
    “action” : sleeping 
}

{   
    “name: paul mary ken, 
    “action” : jumping running eating 
}
```

So far i’ve tried using a simple for loop to iterate over the textfile line by line, checking if a line contains either NAME or ACTION, but I cannot figure out the logic to concatenate and push the values into the array without getting into trouble. I'm learning javascript and could really use a little help solving this problem, thanks in advance.

Comment: Loop over the textfile and assume you have always a name line. If it is true, you can concat a string in a variable called name. If it's not, you create another variable storing the action, create a new object, insert in the object name and action variable, push this object inside the array and restore name variable to empty. Hope it helps

Comment: Edit: in that algorithm, after find an action line you have to assume that the next one is still an action and store It in  a variable. If it's not an action, you have to push a new object into the array and reinizialize the variables you use for store name and action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a similar solution to that of Kevin's. The biggest difference is when it creates new objects and adds them to the array vs. when it just appends to existing values. Hope it helps!

```
var lines = `NAME: joe
ACTION: running
NAME: paul
ACTION: walking
ACTION: swimming
NAME: mary
NAME: joe
ACTION: sleeping
NAME: paul
NAME: mary
NAME: ken
ACTION: jumping
ACTION: running
ACTION: eating`


var entries = [];
var current = null;
lines.split("\n").forEach(function(entry) {

    if (entry.indexOf('NAME:') > -1) {

      var name = entry.substring(6);

      // if the current instance hasn't been set yet,
      // or there is already a value present, start a new object.
      if (!current || current.action) {
        current = { name: name, action: null };
        entries.push(current);
        return;
      }

      // append the new name the current name list
      current.name = `${current.name} ${name}`;
      return;
    }

    // append the new action to the current action list. 
    // if action is null, just set the action as its initial value.
    var action = entry.substring(8);
    current.action = !current.action ? action : `${current.action} ${action}`;
});

console.log(entries);
```

Comment: Btw, the ` around `${current.name} ${name}`, what do they do or mean? I tried typing it with normal quotation marks at first, but that didn't work...

Comment: @JensB it's called a "template literal". One of many great new features in ES6. Here's some more details on it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

You need to first split the string of text by line, then loop over each line and parse the key and value. Here's a working example

```js
var text = `NAME: joe 
ACTION: running 
NAME: paul 
ACTION: walking 
ACTION: swimming 
NAME: mary 
NAME: joe 
ACTION: sleeping 
NAME: paul 
NAME: mary 
NAME: ken 
ACTION: jumping 
ACTION: running 
ACTION: eating`

// split the text in to an array of lines
var lines = text.split("\n")

var data = [] // the final mapped data
var person = null // the person object to add actions to

// loop through each line
lines.forEach(function(line){
  
  // split the line into a key (NAME or ACTION) and the value
  var vals = line.split(': ')
  var key = vals[0]
  var val = vals[1]

  // if this line is for a new name, make a new "person"
  if( key == 'NAME' ){
  
    // save the current person to the final data
    if( person ) data.push(person)
    
    // then create a new one
    person = {name: val, actions: ''}
  
  // add the action to the current person (if there is one)
  }else if( person ){
    person.actions += val
  }

})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: I just noticed this doesn't quite match your desired output, but maybe you can figure it out from here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match()` `RegExp` `/NAME.+(?=\s\n)/g` and `/ACTION.+(?=\s\n)/g` to match lines beginning with `"NAME"` and `"ACTION"`, `.map()` and `.replace()` with `RegExp` `/^[A-Z:\s]+/` to replace `"NAME"`, `"ACTION"`, `":"`, and space characters.

Get greatest array `.length` using `Math.max()` to set as maximum iterations for `for` loop. `.push()` new object to array; if element does not exist at the index of the array which has less `.length`, set empty string `""` as value of property.

```js
var text = `NAME: joe 
ACTION: running 
NAME: paul 
ACTION: walking 
ACTION: swimming 
NAME: mary 
NAME: joe 
ACTION: sleeping 
NAME: paul 
NAME: mary 
NAME: ken 
ACTION: jumping 
ACTION: running 
ACTION: eating`;

var [res, ...[names, actions]] = [[]
                                 , text.match(/NAME.+(?=\s\n)/g)
                                 , text.match(/ACTION.+(?=\s\n)/g)
                                 ].map(function(arr) {
                                    return arr.map(function(value) {
                                      return value.replace(/^[A-Z:\s]+/, "")
                                    })
                                  });

for (var i = 0; i < Math.max(names.length, actions.length); i++) {
  res.push({name:names[i] || "", action: actions[i] || ""})
};

console.log(res);
```